# AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'go_up'

Tags: python, python-turtle

I keep on getting an error saying Player object has no attribute go_up when i have clearly defined it in the player class.

```
Error message: File "C:\Users\mctri\OneDrive\Desktop\Maze
game\src\main.py", line 134, in <module>
        turtle.onkey(player.go_up,"Up")
    AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'go_up'
```

```
import turtle
import random
import math
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys
import winsound

# Creating the window to display maze

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Maze game")
win.bgcolor("grey")
win.setup(width=900, height=900)


#Register shapes
turtle.register_shape("Images/wall.gif")
turtle.register_shape("Images/brick.gif")
turtle.register_shape("Images/brick1.gif")

# Creating blocks class
class Blocks(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("Images/brick1.gif")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
        messagebox.showinfo("Story", "Welcome to an adventure"
                                     "To a scary adventure")

#Creating player class
class Player(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("circle")
        self.color("red")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
        self.gold = 0

#Player movement
def go_up(self):
    move_to_x = player.xcor()
    move_to_y = player.ycor() + 24
    if (move_to_x, move_to_y) not in walls:
        self.goto(move_to_x, move_to_y)

def go_down(self):
    move_to_x = player.xcor()
    move_to_y = player.ycor() - 24
    if (move_to_x, move_to_y) not in walls:
        self.goto(move_to_x, move_to_y)

def go_right(self):
    move_to_x = player.xcor() + 24
    move_to_y = player.xcor()
    if (move_to_x, move_to_y) not in walls:
        self.goto(move_to_x, move_to_y)

def go_left(self):
    move_to_x = player.xcor() -24
    move_to_y = player.xcor()
    if (move_to_x, move_to_y) not in walls:
        self.goto(move_to_x, move_to_y)










# Creating first map
map = [""]
map_1 = [
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "XP       XXXXX   XXXXXXXX",
    "XXXXX    XXXXX   XXXXXXXX",
    "XXXXX    XXXXX   XXXXXXXX",
    "XX                      X",
    "XX          XXXXX  XXXXXX",
    "XX          XXXXX  XX  XX",
    "XX              X  XX  XX",
    "XX          XXXXX  XX  XX",
    "XX     XX   XXXXX  XX  XX",
    "XX     XX              XX",
    "XX     XX     XXXXXXX  XX",
    "XX     XX    TXXXXXXX  XX",
    "XXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXX    XX",
    "XXXXXXXXX        XXXXXXXX",
    "X                      XX",
    "X  XX     XXXXXXXXX    XX",
    "X  XX     XXX    XX    XX",
    "X  XX    TXXX    XX    XX",
    "XXXXX   XXXXX          XX",
    "XXXXX   XXXXX    XX    XX",
    "XXXXX              XXXXXX",
    "XX      XXXXXX     XXXXXX",
    "XX      XXXXXX        XXX",
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

#Creating map setup function
def setup_maze(map):
    for y in range(len(map)):
        for x in range(len(map[y])):
            character = map[y][x]
            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            if character == "X":
                blocks.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                blocks.stamp()

            if character == "P":
                player.goto(screen_x, screen_y)






#Append map
map.append(map_1)

#Creating class instance
blocks = Blocks()
player = Player()

#Keybinding
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(player.go_up,"Up")
turtle.onkey(player.go_down,"Down")
turtle.onkey(player.do_left,"Left")
turtle.onkey(player.go_right,"Right")

#Setup maze map
setup_maze(map[1])

#Create Walls
walls = []

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 2):

`go_up` is not actually in the `Player` class, due to its indentation:

```
class Player(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

#Player movement
def go_up(self):
    ...
```

It has to be the same indentation level as `__init__` in order to be considered a part of the `Player` class:

```
class Player(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    #Player movement
    def go_up(self):
        ...
```

Same goes for `go_down`, `go_right`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is what is used to group functions that are bound to a class, otherwise known as member methods.  Just remember they should be siblings of your `__init__()` class constructor.

```
class Player(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("circle")
        self.color("red")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
        self.gold = 0
    
    #Player movement
    def go_up(self):
        move_to_x = player.xcor()
        move_to_y = player.ycor() + 24
        if (move_to_x, move_to_y) not in walls:
            self.goto(move_to_x, move_to_y)
    
    def go_down(self):
        move_to_x = player.xcor()
        move_to_y = player.ycor() - 24
        if (move_to_x, move_to_y) not in walls:
            self.goto(move_to_x, move_to_y)
```